# How should I edit my pom.xml file to import my maven project to sonarqube?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, sonarqube, build-tools

I am using JDK 1.8 and Maven using Eclipse IDE. I want to analyze my project on SonarQube 6.6. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ADDITION</groupId>
  <artifactId>Addition</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>     <!-- NOT org.junit here -->
  <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
  
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And this is the output with error:
(localhost:9000 is the default port for SonarQube and it is working fine. But the problem is I cannot import my maven project to sonar. If anyone finds the solution, please help.
Thank you.)

```
    C:\eclipse-workspace\Addition>mvn sonar:sonar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The artifact org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.1.2184 has been relocated to org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.1.2184: SonarQube plugin was moved to SonarSource organisation
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< ADDITION:Addition >-----------------
[INFO] Building Addition 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) @ Addition ---
[INFO] User cache: C:\Users\arghy\.sonar\cache
[ERROR] SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.057 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-01T13:58:31+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project Addition: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like localhost resolves to the ipv6 adress, maybe sonarqube doesn't support that. What happens if you change `http://localhost:9000` to `http://127.0.0.1:9000`?

Comment: Still there is error. Anew error is showing now. "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project Addition: Failed to upload report - 500:  -> [Help 1]"

Comment: One step further at least, is 500 the http code from the sonarqube server? If so it's an internal server error and there should be more details in the server log.

Comment: Can you help me on how to solve this error? The error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project Addition: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

Comment: My default sonar maven plugin version is 3.9.2184. and my sonarqube version is 6.6. Are these two compatibles with each other? Do I have to download some other version of sonarqube? If yes, then what is it? Thank You.

Comment: Looks like you are running the latest version of the scanner but a very old version of the server. For the server 9.3 is the lastest server version, 8.9 is the latest LTS (long term support) version. So you need to either update the server (recommended) or downgrade the plugin. Here are the plugin versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin.  Later server versions here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/.